# tkinter couldn't recognize image data

Tags: python, json, tkinter, base64

I want to show a jpg image in tkinter.Label using a base64 string that is stored inside a JSON file, but I get the following error:
**_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize image data**

here's my block of code:

```
import json
import base64
import tkinter as tk

image_data = {}
def image_to_json():
    with open("path/to/image.jpg","rb") as image:
        data = base64.b64encode(image.read())
        image_data["data"]=str(data)
    with open("jsonfile.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(image_data, file)

def json_to_image():
    with open("jsonfile.json", "rb") as file:
        contents = json.load(file)
        img_data = contents["data"]
        return img_data

if __name__=="__main__": 
    root = tk.Tk()
    image_to_json()
    converted_image = tk.PhotoImage(data=json_to_image())
    label = tk.Label(root, image = converted_image).pack()
    root.mainloop
```

I've also tried this using a png file and got the same error

Comment: Have you ever tried to inspect the output of `str(data)`?  Since `data` is of type `bytes`, `str(data)` will be saved into the JSON file something like `"data": "b'....'"`.  You need to use `data.decode()` instead.

Comment: @acw1668, tried this, now the data in json file doesn't have the ` b' ` but still returns the same error

Comment: `tk.PhotoImage()` does not support JPEG image.  I have tried your code with PNG image after using `decode()` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to decode the string properly:

**EDITED** Try this:

```
image_data = {}
with open("path/to/image.png", "rb") as image:
    data = base64.encodebytes(image.read())#
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    image_data["data"] = data
    
    
with open("jsonfile.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(image_data, file)

with open("jsonfile.json", "rb") as file:
    contents = json.load(file)
    image_data = contents["data"]
```

Then it works:

```
root = tk.Tk()
converted_image = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data)
label = tk.Label(root, image = converted_image).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've tried this but still got the same error

Comment: See my updated version. This works on my system using a `png` and `jpeg`.